# jquery 1.5 ajax call giving invalid argument for webmethod in a handler

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I am getting a problem in calling a webmethod inside my http handler. The jquery.js file opens up at some random place and gives a prompt "Invalid Argument"

**Code is as follows:**

JS:

```
var src = "MyHandler.axd";
var id = "1234566";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: src + "/MyMethod?key=" + id,                
    success: function (msgObj) {
        var msg = msgObj.d;            
    },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

C#

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string MyMethod(string key)
    {
        return someLogic;
    }
```

And because of which the ProcessRequest method is being called for the ajax call.

Even tried it with following
Removed httpget and responseformat from c# code.

JS

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: src + "/MyMethod",
    data: "{ 'key':'"+ id +"'}",        
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msgObj) {
        debugger;
        var msg = msgObj.d;

    },
    error: function (e) {
        debugger;

    }
});
```

Comment: Which jquery files is throwing the exception? What jquery files are you referencing?

Comment: Jeff, its jquery-1.5.min.js, and at some random place it is showing "Invalid Argument" in VS2010

Answer (score 0):

Well, not able to find any solution or reason why this behavior!

Kept the same webmethod in a page and its working fine. So added logic to handle the ajax call in process request only. works like a charm.